Immigration at Japan: Do they check approved leave dates?
I had applied for a visa to Japan and got a multi-entry visa.
The things is now I am planning to add 2 more days to my itinerary, making a total of 15 days.
I have a question. Do they ask for NoC from office too at the immigration?
I have a NOC from office for the initial itinerary, but now since I am planning 2 more days, I will be arriving 2 days earlier.
In my office, theres a concept of informal/unofficial leaves also where you just inform your senior. So, I want to take those instead of officially registering. Officially registering costs me money too and no one does it in my company.
My question is will it be a problem at immigration if I won't be having NOC from the employer for the initial 2 days? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Which country are you from?

Is your visa valid from your (new) intended arrival date?

@Traveller, yes It is valid.

@AnishSheela From India. Have a visa for 5 years, valid.

What is a NOC or NoC?

@jkej NOC is a letter from the employer that this employee is allowed to take a break from work, usually including details of employment and of the allowed break.

If your visa is valid, extending a trip for a few days at beginning or end is justified. Usually, you won't be asked anything, if you have your hotel booking and return ticket.
However, if you are asked on why, explain truthfully that you are looking to spend few more days exploring the city.
You won't be asked about leaves and all in most cases. If they do, tell them you asked for permission for two more days and your supervisor approved it. If they still drill further, you can give the contact number for your supervisor. Note that these are extreme cases. In any case, do not lie.
And, do not show the NOC or anything, unless asked. Just show hotel booking and return tickets. Answer things minimally and only if asked. Especially to airline staff and Indian immigration. Although Japan won't have any issues, airline staff and Indian immigration could be overly cautious and may cause issues.

I’d go a bit further: don’t show anything at all unless you are asked.
